# Filter custom listview/create a filter

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, textview

I am developing app with custom `ArrayList` and custom `ListView` the problem is that it only filters by textview2 object. I need to filter atleast by textview1 and textview2.

the custom `ArrayList` contains this:

```
public class favdat {
    public String prece,termins,veic,links;

}
```

and my ArrayAdapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,List<String> at) 
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, at);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlv, parent,false);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView iv2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iv2.setClickable(true);
            tv1.setText(da.get(position).prece);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            tv2.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            tv2.setText(da.get(position).termins);
            data7 = new favdat();
            data7.links = da.get(position).links;
            data7.prece = da.get(position).prece;
            data7.termins = da.get(position).termins;
            data7.veic =
        da.get(position).veic;

            return row;
        }
}
```

and i am using text watcher to filter `ListView` content. But it filters only by `TextView2`
So the question is how can i filter my custom list or how to write the filter for my needs?

Comment: what do you mean by "it only filters by one object, i need to filter atleast by two."? **one or two means**?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani Sorry, as you might see in my ArrayAddapter there is 3 textviews i need to create a filter which will show me those elements in the listview which has the value which i entered.

Comment: @silent as i'm new to android development i don't know how to make my own filter